# Handle a lot of data with graphs

Tags: java, graph

I have a crawler which crawl only one website. But a website can have thousand pages. 
Each page is a vertex, I use `JGraphT` for that.

But If I crawl a huge website, I get a `StackOverflowError` after a moment.

How can I do to handle a lot of data in this case ?
I have to use a database ?
There is a library which handle this specific kind of data (vertex, edge,...) in a database ?

Thanks

Comment: it would be great if you accepted the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wanna use [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) which is a high performance, NOSQL graph database.